# Find minimum sum of the list optimally using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to solve the coding challenge which states that:

Given a list 'L' and number of replacements 'k'.

Step 1: In iteration 1 find any number from 'L', make it half and replace it with integer by rounding off.
Step 2: Iterate Step 1 for 'k' such operation such that at last we get the `minimum sum` of all elements in list "L'.

Example:

```
   L=[1,2,2,3] k=4
     [1,2,2,2] replaced 3 by 2 ( round(3/2)=2)
     [1,2,2,1] replaced 2 by 1
     [1,2,1,1] replaced 2 by 1
     [1,1,1,1] replaced 2 by 1
```

So the sum is 4 and its minimum.
Note: The array might not be sorted.

I tried this approach:

```
        def fun(L,k):
           for i in range(k):
                L.sort()
                num=round(L[-1]/2)
                L[-1]=num
           return sum(L)
```

This approach is showing "Timed Out" due to time complexity.

Is there any optimal way to solve this.

Comment: Can you link to the coding challenge? Also, +1 for an interesting question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4]

def fun(L, K):
    return sum([round(i/2) for i in L])

print(fun(nums, 4))
```

see [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) if you are confused about this syntax.